Density of $C_c$ in $L^1$ for non strictly positive Radon measure
Suppose that $X$ is a Hausdorff locally compact space, and $\mu$ is a Radon measure on its Borel $\sigma$-algebra.
-I know that if $\mu$ is strictly positive then the space of continuous function with compact support $C_c(X)$ injects into $L^1(X)$, the injection being the canonical one, by identifying a function with its equivalence class of almost everywhere equality. Let's call $\pi$ this identification map.
-It is also known that $C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^1(X,\mu)$, without the hypothesis of $\mu$ being strictly positive.
My question is then : what does the last statement mean ? Do we mean that $\pi(C_c(X))$ is dense in $L^1(X,\mu)$  ?

What is a strictly positive measure?

A measure that is such that any non-empty open set has nonzero measure

Do we mean that $\pi(C_c(X))$ is dense in $L^1(X,\mu)$  ?: YES.
